# XML node to table if condition is true (C# , ASP.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am just beginning C# and ASP.Net and I need help populating a table. 
This is how the xml looks like:

```
`<client>
  <person>
    <id>12345</id>
    <name>John</name>
    <surname>Smith</surname>
    <type>New</type>
   </person>
</client>`
```

I want to enter the id in a text field, press a submit button and if the id matches with one of the ids from the xml file to populate a table with name. So far if I press the button nothing happens.

This is my aspx so far (I believe `"</asp:DataList>"` should be at the end, but if I do so it will give an error):

```
  <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">



    <asp:XmlDataSource ID="SalaDataSource" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/clienti.xml" XPath="/clienti/persoana" ></asp:XmlDataSource>
    <asp:DataList ID="dlPerson" runat="server" DataSourceID="SalaDataSource"> </asp:DataList>

    <h2>Verify member</h2><br/>

         <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:10px;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;" >
                    Card ID
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left:20px;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="Button1_Click" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                    </td>

                </tr>
        </table><br/>       


    <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:10px;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;" >
                    Name 
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left:10px;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;" >
                    Surname
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left:20px;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;">
                    Type
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:10px;" valign="top"> <%# XPath("name")%>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left:20px;" valign="top"> <%# XPath("surname") %>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left:20px;" valign="top"> <%# XPath("type")%>
            </tr>
         </ItemTemplate>

       <FooterTemplate>
           <tr>
            <td colspan ="3"> 
            </td>
           </tr>
            </table>
       </FooterTemplate><br/>



 </asp:Content>
```

and this is the aspx.cs:

```
 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h1><p>Sala fitness</p></h1>

    <asp:XmlDataSource ID="SalaDataSource" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/clienti.xml" XPath="/clienti/persoana" ></asp:XmlDataSource>
    <asp:DataList ID="dlPerson" runat="server" DataSourceID="SalaDataSource"> </asp:DataList>

    <h2>Verify member</h2><br/>

         <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:10px;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;" >
                    Card ID
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left:20px;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="Button1_Click" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                    </td>

                </tr>
        </table><br/>       


    <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:10px;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;" >
                    Name 
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left:10px;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;" >
                    Surname
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left:20px;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;">
                    Type
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:10px;" valign="top"> <%# XPath("name")%>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left:20px;" valign="top"> <%# XPath("surname") %>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left:20px;" valign="top"> <%# XPath("type")%>
            </tr>
         </ItemTemplate>

       <FooterTemplate>
           <tr>
            <td colspan ="3"> 
            </td>
           </tr>
            </table>
       </FooterTemplate><br/>

    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">Inregistreaza client nou</asp:HyperLink>

 </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Your `aspx.cs` looks like `aspx`

Comment: You forgot to add `.cs` code

Answer (score 0):

Here is what should be your approach to use XMLDataSource in C#:

- Create POCOs to map your XML document
- Deserialize your XML using XmlSerializer (This way you will get the list of Clients)

Now do

```
var clientObject=  clientList.where(t=>t.id==textbox1.Text).FirstOrDefult();
```

Now use this object's properties to bind a datatable.